# VLC media kit not getting properly installed

Tags: ios, swift, vlc, symbols

I am using VLC media player to stream rtsp links. When added the vlc media kit, i am able to use the VLC media player delegate which is referenced properly but when i am using VLC media player its showing this error: Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_VLCMedia", referenced from:       objc-class-ref in StreamDetailVC.o

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem and it took a lot of efforts to fix get this done.

1. Create a dummy Xcode project, download MobileVLCkit using cocoa pods. Mention the platform iOS to 12.0 in podfile if you are using Xcode 10.
2. Copy the downloaded "MobileVLCKit.framework" file from the dummy project, into your project root folder. No need to add the framework reference in the project.
3. Go to your project's target build settings and add the following lines to your "Header Search Paths" (add the quotes too)
   "$(PROJECT_DIR)/MobileVLCKit.framework/Headers"
   "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
4. In your project's target build settings add the following lines to your framework search paths (add the quotes too)
   "$(SRCROOT)/MobileVLCKit.framework"
   "$(PROJECT_DIR)"
5. in Other linker flags add the following lines
   -l"bz2"
   -l"iconv"
   -framework
   "MobileVLCKit"
6. In General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries add the following library by clicking on the + icon
   libc++.tbd (Xcode 10)
   libstdc++.6.tbd (< xcode 10)
7. Most important of all add the reference to the Bridging-Header.h by including the following line
   #import "MobileVLCKit/MobileVLCKit.h"
8. Test by typing VLCMediaPlayerDelegate, see if that auto completes. If so help others by pointing them here, else retrace your steps to see what you have missed.
9. Add all below frameworks:

   - AudioToolbox.framework
   - AVFoundation.framework
   - CFNetwork.framework
   - CoreFoundation.framework
   - CoreGraphics.framework
   - CoreMedia.framework
   - CoreText.framework
   - CoreVideo.framework
   - Foundation.framework
   - libbz2.tbd
   - libiconv.tbd
   - OpenGLES.framework
   - QuartzCore.framework
   - Security.framework
   - VideoToolbox.framework

On iOS and tvOS, you also need to link:

- UIKit.framework

Hope that helps.
I was able to solve this by the below given link.
Source: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=137065
https://code.videolan.org/videolan/VLCKit#installation